# Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Tags: r, function, exception, save, coding-style

My code is as follows,

```
`FARS = read.csv("C:\\Users\\rb138\\Desktop\\FARS.csv", header = T, sep = ",", na.strings=c(""," ","NA-code","NA"))


Preprocessing = process() {

  FARS$X = NULL
  library(caTools)
  is.na(FARS) <- FARS == "NULL"
  miss<-function(x)
  {
    return(sum(is.na(x)/length(x)*100))
  }
  apply(FARS,2,FUN = miss)
  Mode <- function (x, na.rm) {
    xtab <- table(x)
    xmode <- names(which(xtab == max(xtab)))
    if (length(xmode) > 1) xmode <- ">1 mode"
    return(xmode)
  }
  for (var in 1:ncol(FARS)) {
    if (class(FARS[,var])=="numeric") {
      FARS[is.na(FARS[,var]),var] <- mean(FARS[,var], na.rm = TRUE)
    } else if (class(FARS[,var]) %in% c("character", "factor")) {
      FARS[is.na(FARS[,var]),var] <- Mode(FARS[,var], na.rm = TRUE)
    }
    }
  set.seed(45)
  split = sample.split(FARS$airbagDeploy, SplitRatio = 0.70)
  Train1 = subset(FARS, split == TRUE)
  Test1 = subset(FARS, split == FALSE)

  }`
```

If is pass it outside the object it is not throwing any error. But when i am running it inside the function its throwing the following exception:

`Error: unexpected '}' in "  }"`

Also when i trying to save the Object in a RDS file, code as follows :

`saveRDS(Preprocessing, file = "preprocessing_script.rds")`

its is throwing the following exception :

`Error in saveRDS(Preprocessing, file = "preprocessing_script.rds") : 
  object 'Preprocessing' not found`

Data set used for this is FARS.csv from the package "gamclass" in R.
In case if anyone requires the dataset, kindly as in your comments.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what are you trying here? `Preprocessing = process() {` to create a new function? if so then the syntax is wrong

Comment: I am trying to put the whole pre-processing script in a single object.

Comment: Whe not have it in a separate file and `source()` that file? also in that file, you could define your function `Preprocessing <- function( ){ your code }` and call it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your code like this with separate function:

```
FARS = read.csv("C:\\Users\\rb138\\Desktop\\FARS.csv", header = T, sep = ",", na.strings=c(""," ","NA-code","NA"))


Preprocessing = function(FARS) {

  FARS$X = NULL
  library(caTools)
  is.na(FARS) <- FARS == "NULL"
  miss<-function(x)
  {
    return(sum(is.na(x)/length(x)*100))
  }
  apply(FARS,2,FUN = miss)
  Mode <- function (x, na.rm) {
    xtab <- table(x)
    xmode <- names(which(xtab == max(xtab)))
    if (length(xmode) > 1) xmode <- ">1 mode"
    return(xmode)
  }
  for (var in 1:ncol(FARS)) {
    if (class(FARS[,var])=="numeric") {
      FARS[is.na(FARS[,var]),var] <- mean(FARS[,var], na.rm = TRUE)
    } else if (class(FARS[,var]) %in% c("character", "factor")) {
      FARS[is.na(FARS[,var]),var] <- Mode(FARS[,var], na.rm = TRUE)
    }
    }
  set.seed(45)
  split = sample.split(FARS$airbagDeploy, SplitRatio = 0.70)
  Train1 = subset(FARS, split == TRUE)
  Test1 = subset(FARS, split == FALSE)

  }

Preprocessing(FARS)
```

Let me know if it works!